# $C(x) = x^{1/5}(x + 6)$ Find Where the Function Increases and Decreases

Tags: calculus

I believe this has something to do with my Algebra. I am stuck as to how to evaluate this local minimum and maximum. Also, my sign chart. Do I have too many intervals? If so why. [image]

Comment: $x=0$ is not a solution to $$\dfrac{6(x+1)}{5\sqrt[4]{x^5}}=0$$

Comment: Can you explain why since 0 cannot be a value in the denominator, I thought it a critical point.

Comment: Ahh you're correct about $x=0$ giving a critical point but a critical point need not be a minimum or maximum right ? let us also keep in mind the graph of $c(x)$ eventhough it is not necessary. see [this graph of c(x)](http://gyazo.com/41a013aace974df02337cbdf9b114197)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think $x=0$ is not a critical point. To see this, look at the derivative $f'(x)$ you wrote in the first line: $$f'(x) = \frac{6}{5}x^{1/5} + \frac{6}{5}x^{-4/5}.$$
This function is actually not defined in $x=0$. Still one could have that $\lim_{x\to 0} f'(x) = 0$, but this is not the case. Indeed, note that $x^{-4/5} \to \infty$ as $x\to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative can be easily computed with the (formal) logarithmic method:
$$
\log f(x)=\frac{1}{5}\log x+\log(x+6)
$$
so
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{1}{5x}+\frac{1}{x+6}=\frac{6(x+1)}{5x(x+6)}
$$
and therefore
$$
f'(x)=\frac{6(x+1)}{5x(x+6)}\sqrt[5]{x}(x+6)=
\frac{6(x+1)}{5\sqrt[5]{x^4}}
$$
However, also your method is sound.

This expression is undefined at $0$ and indeed the function is not differentiable at $0$.

Thus we have *two* points to take care of: $-1$, where the derivative vanishes, and $0$, where the derivative doesn't exist.

However, the derivative is positive in a neighborhood of $0$ (excluding $0$), so it is increasing both at the left and at the right of $0$. [**Note:** *this is where you're wrong.*]

The point $-1$ is a point of minimum, because the derivative is negative at the left and positive at the right of $-1$.

Note that this is confirmed by the fact that
$$
\lim_{x\to-\infty}\sqrt[5]{x}(x+6)=\infty=
\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt[5]{x}(x+6)
$$
so the function *must* have a minimum, being continuous.

Note also that a critical point need not be either a maximum or a minimum: $0$ is a critical point of $f(x)=x^3$, but it's clearly neither a maximum nor a minimum.